# How to edit css for `<TH></TH>` headers in `HTMLTable`?

Tags: html, css

I want to change the border colors surrounding my header tables from the default grey given by the package`HTMLTable` to black. I cannot figure this out for some reason. I've tried the following:

```
htmlTable(data, css.table = "margin-top: 0.5px; margin-bottom: 0.5px; border: 1.5px solid black;", css.cgroup="border-bottom: 1px solid black; border-top: 1.5px solid black; text-align: center;", file = "data.html")
```

I've also changed `css.cgroup` to `css.rgroup` but nothing happens. Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There must be a better way to do this using the HTMLTable package, but this will do the trick:

```
mytableout <-htmlTable(data)

sink("data.html")
cat("<style>th {border-bottom: 1px solid black !important;border-top: 2px solid black !important;}</style>")
print(mytableout,type="html",useViewer=TRUE)
sink()
```

Black:

[image: Black]

Grey:

[image: Grey]